# failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 302

Tags: java, websocket, webrtc, tomcat8

I'm learning about webrtc and followed the instructions here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/webrtc/webrtc_rtcpeerconnection_apis.htm

I'm using **tomcat v8.0** for deploying my web application, I got following error in **Console Window :**

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8080/Connection' failed: Error
>   during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 302

My webapplication works fine, if I use http://localhost:8080/Connection/
link in url locator. If I use `ws://localhost:8080/Connection` in url locator, Im getting:

> This site can’t be reached

I cannot figure out why I am getting 302. Can anyone help me to resolve this?

Comment: is your application fronted by an Apache ?

Comment: Yep,Apache Tomcat8

Comment: I mean do you use an Apache httpd (web server) to front your Tomcat ? In which case you probably have to inform the web server (httpd) that the Websocket protocol comes into play

Comment: Or, are your requests directly hitting the Tomcat

Comment: directly hitting the Tomcat,I'm using eclipse IDE for developing java  web application.deploying my project using tomcat8

Comment: Is this path is secured by spring security or something else. Once logout your session and try to open http://localhost:8080/Connection/ status code 302 means your request is being redirected, so you should check security settings and filters

Answer (score 1):

You try this input
The browser:http://localhost:8080
The WebSocket:ws://localhost:8080/Connection
The browser can not be http://127.0.0.1